# No compatible version found: coffee-script@'^1.6.3'

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

The first few times I ran this build on heroku this dependency installed fine. Now it said it is not available. However if I run...

npm install coffee-script@'^1.6.3'

From the command line I can install it locally fine. Why is heroku saying it can't find it?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Can you add the output of `npm install` to your question?

Comment: I lost the error message but when I removed the 'engine' declaration from the package.json it magically started working!